# Is it possible to render ZIP code borders with acceptable performance using “HERE Maps API for JavaScript”?

Tags: javascript, here-api

There are about 4500 ZIP codes which I would like to render over the country. Each ZIP code polygon is precise enough and has a lot of points (vertices). I need to be able to interact with each ZIP code individually (highlight it on mouse hover).

With my current implementation the performance is not sufficient. Rendering/re-rendering is slow (rendering performs by parts) as well as highlighting (changing of fillColor via setStyle()).

How it is implemented:

- all data is stored and passed into HERE Maps as GeoJSON. Separate GeoJSON for each of 4500 ZIP code;
- H.data.geojson.Reader() is used;
- H.map.Group is created and all Polygons are added to this group;

How it is optimized:

- All polygons are simplified as much as possible (actually I would like to avoid this but looks like it's impossible)
- Only polygons which intersect with bounding box of map view are rendered. It's 70 - 180 polygons per one rendering. I do not render all 4500 polygons. When I pan the map on 'mapviewchangeend' I remove all objects from the group using group.removeAll() and add new ones based on changed bounding box.

Is this result of rendering performance expected with such amount of polygons or have I made something wrong in my logic? Maybe there is another way which allow to render ZIP codes with acceptable performance?

Code:

```
class GCM {
private m_areasDataCache: Map<number, object[]> = new Map();
private m_map: H.Map;
private m_currentDataLevel?: number;
private m_areasGroup: H.map.Group;
private m_shallRenderAreas = true;
private m_preloadingStatus = 0; // 0 - Preloading hasn't been happen yet
private m_servicesURL = "http://localhost:3000/";
private m_lastActiveArea: H.map.Polygon;
private m_normalAreaStyle = {
    fillColor: 'rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.3)',
    strokeColor: 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 1)',
    lineWidth: 1
};
private m_activeAreaStyle = {
    fillColor: 'rgba(255, 0, 0, 1)',
    strokeColor: 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 1)',
    lineWidth: 1
};

startApp() {
    this.setupMap();
}

async renderAreas() {
    if (this.m_shallRenderAreas === false) {
        return;
    }

    const dataLevel = this.getDataLevel(this.m_map.getZoom());
    if (
        // do not render areas again if they already rendered
        this.m_currentDataLevel === dataLevel
        // in case of zip code level perform rendering in order to take into account new bounding box
        && dataLevel !== 4
    ) {
        return;
    }

    this.m_currentDataLevel = dataLevel;

    let areas = [];
    if (!this.m_areasDataCache.has(dataLevel)) {
        const areasData = await this.readData(this.m_servicesURL + "?level=" + dataLevel);
        areas = JSON.parse(areasData);

        this.m_areasDataCache.set(dataLevel, areas);
    } else {
        areas = this.m_areasDataCache.get(dataLevel);
    }

    // cleanup the layer by removing objects from the group
    const group = this.getAreasGroup();
    group.removeAll();

    for (const area of areas) {
        if (this.isInBoundingBox(area.bounding_box)) {
            this.renderAreasPolygons(area);
        }
    }

    // it's time to pre-load zip codes polygones
    // TODO: it is possible to preload also other levels if needed
    if (!this.m_areasDataCache.has(4) && this.m_preloadingStatus === 0) {
        this.m_preloadingStatus = 1; // 1 - Preloading started
        this.preloadData().then(() => {
            this.m_preloadingStatus = 2; // 2 - Preloading finished
        });
    }
}

/**
 * Some data, such as Zip Codes polygons can be preloaded when the application is in idle state
 * in order to be ready to render it as soon as possible when it will be required.
 */
private async preloadData() {
    const dataLevel = 4;
    const areasData = await this.readData(this.m_servicesURL + "?level=" + dataLevel);
    const areas = JSON.parse(areasData);
    this.m_areasDataCache.set(dataLevel, areas);
}

private isInBoundingBox(areaBoundingBox: any): boolean {
    if (areaBoundingBox === null) {
        return true;
    }

    // json bounding box
    const areaRect = new H.geo.Rect(
        areaBoundingBox.TopLeft.Latitude,
        areaBoundingBox.TopLeft.Longitude,
        areaBoundingBox.BottomRight.Latitude,
        areaBoundingBox.BottomRight.Longitude
    );

    const mapViewBoundingBox = (this.m_map.getViewModel() as any).getLookAtData().bounds.getBoundingBox();
    const isInBoundingBox = mapViewBoundingBox.intersects(areaRect);

    return isInBoundingBox;
}

private getDataLevel(zoomLevel: number): number {
    let dataLevel = 0; // Country

    if (zoomLevel > 5 && zoomLevel <= 6) {
        dataLevel = 1; // NUTS 1
    } else if (zoomLevel > 6 && zoomLevel <= 7) {
        dataLevel = 2; // NUTS 2
    } else if (zoomLevel > 7 && zoomLevel <= 10) {
        dataLevel = 3; // NUTS 3
    } else if (zoomLevel > 10) {
        dataLevel = 4; // ZIP
    }

    return dataLevel;
}

private areaStyle(mapObjects: H.map.Object[]) {
    for (const mapObject of mapObjects) {
        if (mapObject instanceof H.map.Polygon) {
            mapObject.setStyle(this.m_normalAreaStyle);
        }
    }
}

private renderAreasPolygons(area: any) {
    var reader = new (H.data as any).geojson.Reader(undefined, {
        // This function is called each time parser detects a new map object
        style: (mapObject: H.map.Polygon | H.map.Group) => {
            if (mapObject instanceof H.map.Polygon) {
                this.areaStyle([mapObject]);
            } else if (mapObject instanceof H.map.Group) {
                this.areaStyle(mapObject.getObjects());
            }
        }
    });
    reader.parseData(area.shape);

    const objects = reader.getParsedObjects();
    if (objects.length > 1) {
        console.error("There are some unhandled area objects.");
    }
    const object = objects[0];

    const group = this.getAreasGroup();
    group.addObject(object);
}

private getAreasGroup() {
    // https://developer.here.com/documentation/maps/api_reference/H.map.Group.html
    if (this.m_areasGroup === undefined) {
        this.m_areasGroup = new H.map.Group({ zIndex: 10, volatility: true } as any);
        this.m_map.addObject(this.m_areasGroup);
    }

    return this.m_areasGroup;
}

private readData(url: string): Promise<string> {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        const request = new XMLHttpRequest();
        request.open('GET', url, true);
        request.send(null);
        request.onreadystatechange = () => {
            if (request.response && request.readyState == 4) {
                resolve(request.response);
            }
        }
    });
}

private setupMap() {
    const apikey = '';

    // Initialize the platform object:
    const platform = new H.service.Platform({
        apikey
    } as any);

    // Obtain the default map types from the platform object
    const maptypes = platform.createDefaultLayers();

    // Instantiate (and display) a map object:
    this.m_map = new H.Map(
        document.getElementById("mapContainer"),
        (maptypes as any).vector.normal.map,
        {
            zoom: 6,
            center: { lng: 10, lat: 42 }
        });

    // Enable the event system on the map instance:
    const mapEvents = new H.mapevents.MapEvents(this.m_map);

    new H.mapevents.Behavior(mapEvents);

    H.ui.UI.createDefault(this.m_map, maptypes, 'en-US');

    this.m_map.addEventListener('mapviewchangeend', () => {
        this.renderAreas();
    });

    this.m_map.addEventListener('tap', async (event: any) => {
        if (!(event.target instanceof H.map.Polygon)) {
            return;
        }

        if (this.m_lastActiveArea) {
            this.m_lastActiveArea.setStyle(this.m_normalAreaStyle);
        }

        event.target.setStyle(this.m_activeAreaStyle);
        this.m_lastActiveArea = event.target;
    });
}
```

}

const gcm = new GCM();
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", () => gcm.startApp());

Comment: Do you set volatility for the main H.map.Group object?

Comment: https://developer.here.com/documentation/maps/api_reference/H.map.Polygon.html#.Options

Comment: Thanks for feedback. Looks like it works better but now group.removeAll(); doesn't affects rendered polygons. Actually it removes objects from group but polygons stay rendered on the map. Any hint?

Comment: Can you please share your code how you create polygons, how you add them to group as well as how you remove them on "mapviewchangeend"?

Comment: Sure. Code added.

Comment: I think the problem could be inside renderAreasPolygons()? line: 'const object = objects[0];' only adds first parsed object to the group.

Comment: Thank you for your effort. What the problem do you mean? Slow performance or the fact that group.removeAll(); doesn't work properly with volatility: true? I don't think the problem with renderAreasPolygons() because: 1) less objects means better performance 2) there is always only one parsed object since I never receive error "There are some unhandled area objects." which has to be in console if more then one object parsed.

Comment: I see now. I am able to reproduce the issue with removing objects from volatile group. It's a bug on API side.
I found a workaround: Instead of making Group volatile, do set volatility for all parsed objects: `reader.getParsedObjects().forEach(object) {object.setVolatility(true)};`

Comment: With this workaround your solution works without issues. But your solution doesn't solve the problem of performance. It just wait for all calculations and renders everything at once without partial drawing. So now I have to wait up to 4 seconds between my click on polygon and actual changing of fill color. Only simplification of polygons can help but this brings another problems since simplified polygons don't connect perfectly on borders.

Comment: I am not sure what could be the problem. Probably you should simplify your polygons. I created simple geoJSON example with country borders. Moving mouse over polygon updates it's style. The performance is reasonable: https://jsfiddle.net/49h8bs12/

Comment: I have checked your example which seems to work with really reasonable performance but when I change .geojson to https://raw.githubusercontent.com/openpolis/geojson-italy/master/geojson/limits_IT_provinces.geojson with higher precision the performance becomes slower. So, the solution is really only simplification. However, I try to render polygons received from HERE Geocoder and it has't possibility to request data with different precisions. So, I have to post-process all data using some algorithm which will keep all neighbor polygons connected without intersections and holes. Only this way?

Comment: I see your point. I checked with your geojson file and the performance is indeed slow.
There is maybe another temporary solution for you. If you don't need map tilting, rotating and customized vector tiles, you could switch to legacy 2D engine, which gives better performance for such complex polygons (for now). Check this jsfiddle example with your geojson file: https://jsfiddle.net/hy6uwap0/. It's pretty fast.

Comment: Thank you Tomas very much! I've taken all your suggestions into account while presenting HERE Maps possibilities to the end-client.

Answer (score 0):

Try to store your geometries into a layer of Fleet Telematics Custom Location Extension (CLE) and then display them with JS library.

Storing geometries into CLE layer: [User's guide](http://documentation.developer.here.com/pdf/location_custom_hlp/2.5.10/Fleet%20Telematics%20Custom%20Locations%20v2.5.10%20User%20Guide.pdf) and [Developer's guide](http://documentation.developer.here.com/pdf/location_custom_hlp/2.5.10/Fleet%20Telematics%20Custom%20Locations%20v2.5.10%20Developer's%20Guide.pdf)

Displaying a CLE layer with HERE JS library: [Developer's guide](http://documentation.developer.here.com/pdf/maps_js_html5_hlp/3.1.0.0/Maps%20API%20for%20JavaScript%20v3.1.0.0%20Developer's%20Guide.pdf)